# Converting Native Action Bar to Action Bar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

usually learn best by studying working examples and hacking together bits and pieces 
until I understand how everything works. I dont have much experience with `ActionBars` or `ABS` , but I found a working demo of a native `ActionBar`. I found here: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar

I got this demo AND the `ABS library` up and running in eclipse. My question now is **how would I go about converting this to a ABS action bar OR recreate the equivalent using ABS ?( Just a simple starter ABS action bar I can get comfortable with, with several items that link to different activitys. )**

Here is the Action Bar demo code:

```
package com.markupartist.android.actionbar.example;

import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar;
import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.Action;
import com.markupartist.android.widget.ActionBar.IntentAction;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
        //actionBar.setHomeAction(new IntentAction(this, createIntent(this), R.drawable.ic_title_home_demo));
        actionBar.setTitle("Home");

        final Action shareAction = new IntentAction(this, createShareIntent(), R.drawable.ic_title_share_default);
        actionBar.addAction(shareAction);
        final Action otherAction = new IntentAction(this, new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class), R.drawable.ic_title_export_default);
        actionBar.addAction(otherAction);

        Button startProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_progress);
        startProgress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        Button stopProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_progress);
        stopProgress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                actionBar.setProgressBarVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        Button removeActions = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_actions);
        removeActions.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                actionBar.removeAllActions();
            }
        });

        Button addAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_action);
        addAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                actionBar.addAction(new Action() {
                    @Override
                    public void performAction(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Added action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public int getDrawable() {
                        return R.drawable.ic_title_share_default;
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Button removeAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_action);
        removeAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int actionCount = actionBar.getActionCount();
                actionBar.removeActionAt(actionCount - 1);
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Removed action." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Button removeShareAction = (Button) findViewById(R.id.remove_share_action);
        removeShareAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                actionBar.removeAction(shareAction);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Intent createIntent(Context context) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        return i;
    }

    private Intent createShareIntent() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Shared from the ActionBar widget.");
        return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActionBarSherlock is an API-complete backport of the API 14 & 15 action bar which is part of Android.

If you are new to the library I suggest you first attempt to learn how to use the [native action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Only after you are familiar with using it, switch to using ABS.

The switch will be incredibly easy as it mostly consists of these three things:

- Changing a few imports (e.g., `ActionBar`, `MenuItem`) from `android.app` to `com.actionbarsherlock.app` and `android.view` to `com.actionbarsherlock.view`.
- Changing your theme from `Theme.Holo` to `Theme.Sherlock` (or `.Light` or `.Light.DarkActionBar`)
- Changing your activity to extend from `SherlockActivity` instead of `Activity`.
- Switching calls to `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`.

Easy as pie!

Also, it should be noted that your demo is not of the native action bar, but of a third-party library which emulates an action bar from before it was built in to the OS.